# How much drag/friction does moving a magnet past coil make?

Tags: magnetic-fields

In the pic below in Fig . 1 I understand this as a very crude way of generating an electrical charge / voltage in the wire if the magnet shown is moved along the length of the wire..

In Fig.2 there is a coil version of this with the magnets rotating inside the coil so you never reach the end and have to stop. from my understanding this will work the same as in Fig .1 as to make and electrical charge / voltage

The question I have is how much drag would be applied to the axle in Fig. 2 due to eddy currents? or would this be negligible as it's essentially laminated like how you would reduce eddy currents within a transformer..

the reason I ask is, if I had high speed but extremely low torque would this method give the least resistance compared to other configurations of the general different orientations of magnets and coils that most other versions use?

also in fig. 3 I know if the magnet is moved through the middle of the coil this ill will generate a current but how would the efficiency differ for the orientation in Fig. 2

[image: Coils and magnets]

P.S. if you would like to to add any other ways to do this with low torque please do..

Thank you for your time